# Terminating Eclipse console using Java Code

Tags: java

Is there a way of terminating the eclipse console by writing a java code rather than pressing on the red button in the console.
I have tried to read online regarding this, could not find something sensible.

Some programmers suggest the use of System.out.flush()... did not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.flush()` does a completely different thing - it doesn't terminate the current process, but flushes the `OutputStream` of the `System` class.

You can try with this statement:

```
System.exit(0);
```

It's [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) says

> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine.

which I believe is the thing you need.

Please, before using the `System.exit()` method, get familiar with what the javadoc states.

Comment: It is, yes. He should read the javadoc carefully, before using it.

Comment: Thank you kocko for the comment... I think it works in my case but the problem I am embedding an 'expect' code into my machine and there are certain commands when I use, it just keeps the console running for example when I try to 'exit' or 'logout' a machine, the program keeps running till I have to press the red button or simply force the thread to be killed using your command.

Comment: @Sinan Try debugging your application and look what threads are running when you expect your program to terminate

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the red button in the Console sends a signal to the currently running JVM to terminate. As a result of this, your Java Application will terminate as well.

To terminate your Java Program and the JVM behind it, you have two options:

1. Call `System.exit(0)` or with any other exit code (insteaf of 0) - this will lead the JVM to terminate with the given exit code

   Terminate all currently running Java Threads. If no Java Thread is running anymore (e.g. your `main`-Method finished without starting another thread), the JVM will terminate with exit value 0.

After your program isn't running anymore, Eclipse will display your program as terminated and disable the red button in the Console.

And `System.out.flush()` hasn't anything to do with this ...

Comment: Thank you for your post. Please read my comment on Kocko post.